# How to Create GeneratePreSignedUrlRequest to Download Encrypted File

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt files with Server Side Encryption. I'm using Amazon Aws Sdk and Java. I want to do server side encryption with customer - provided encryption keys.

I follow this guide:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/sse-c-using-java-sdk.html

I get this error:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method
```

I have two methods for this operation: `encryptAndUpload()` and `decryptAndDownload()`.

This is my `encryptAndUpload()` method. I'm using signature version 4. I think this method works fine.

```
    public void encryptAndUpload(byte[] salt, char[] password, InputStream stream, String key, String bucket){
       SecretKey secretKey = deriveKey(password, salt);
       SSECustomerKey sseCustomerKey = new SSECustomerKey(secretKey);

       ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration().withSignerOverride("AWSS3V4SignerType");
       AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new PropertiesCredentials(AmazonS3Uploader.class.getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties"));
       AmazonS3 amazonS3EncryptionClient = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, clientConfiguration);
       amazonS3EncryptionClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));

       PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, stream, new ObjectMetadata()).withSSECustomerKey(sseCustomerKey);
       PutObjectResult response = amazonS3EncryptionClient.putObject(putObjectRequest);
}
```

This is my `decryptAndDownload()` method. As you can see, creating keys and amazonS3 parts are identical.

```
    public URL decryptAndDownload(byte[] salt, char[] password, String key, String bucket) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException{
       SecretKey secretKey = deriveKey(password, salt);
       SSECustomerKey sseCustomerKey = new SSECustomerKey(secretKey);

       ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration().withSignerOverride("AWSS3V4SignerType");
       AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new PropertiesCredentials(AmazonS3Uploader.class.getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties"));
       AmazonS3 amazonS3EncryptionClient = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, clientConfiguration);
       amazonS3EncryptionClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));

       GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key).withSSECustomerKey(sseCustomerKey);
       S3Object s3Object = amazonS3EncryptionClient.getObject(getObjectRequest);

       GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(s3Object.getBucketName(), s3Object.getKey(), HttpMethod.GET).withSSECustomerKey(sseCustomerKey);

       URL url = amazonS3EncryptionClient.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

       return url;
}
```

Now, I guess creating `generatePresignedUrlRequest` is the problem. But I don't know how to solve it. I appreciate any help. I can add my `deriveKey` method, but I think my parameters and `deriveKey` method is correct.

Edit: I add my `deriveKey` method for clarity:

```
    private SecretKey deriveKey(char[] password, byte[] salt) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

       SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
       KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 256);
       SecretKey tempSecretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
       SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tempSecretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

       return secretKey;
}
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem ?

Comment: No. I've used Crypto library for encryption.